# How is the Google Analytics Tracking code working? (async method call?)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-analytics-api

This code is the Google Analytics tracking code. How is not make an error because of undifened ga method?

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanded, the script looks like this:

```
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

You'll notice that `'ga'` is the fifth parameter passed to the function, and `window` is the first. Inside the initialization, the first couple lines set `i[r]`, aka `window['ga']` to a function. And there you go!