# How does Google Analytics JavaScript function load and run without async / race condition problems?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-analytics

When installing Google Analytics the latest version of their code (for Universal Analytics) is as follows:

```
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The first part of the code creates a `<script>` tag to load `analytics.js`, then the second part uses the `ga()` function to activate the script.

My question is - if it takes some time to load `analytics.js`, how does the `ga()` function know to wait before being executed? Why doesn't `ga()` try to run before the script has loaded?

I'd like to use a similar mechanism and hoped understanding Google's code better will help.

Comment: I have found this question now after further research http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474151/how-is-the-google-analytics-tracking-code-working-async-method-call?rq=1 which kind of answers my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was more clear in the the `ga.js` codebase than it is here, but it's the exact same principle.

1. Create an empty array (think of it as a queue)
2. Push commands to this array
3. Once the JS file loads, run through the array and execute the commands
4. Finally, overwrite the method that pushes to the array to parse & execute the commands

For `analytics.js` it's pretty much the same thing but wrapped in a function (which can be renamed). To answer your question, the link you sent pretty much sums it up but for clarity: since the code block includes the initialization for the temporary solution (push the commands to the array but not actually execute the commands), `ga()` exists and therefore will run without error.